# Invalid syntax error in Django form translate

Tags: python, django, syntax, django-modeltranslation

I try translate my forms.py (placeholder, choices, etc) but i take syntax error. my code is here;

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CreatePollForm(forms.Form):
        title = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, label="", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1','cols':'20', 'placeholder': (_'Type your question here'),'class': 'createpoll_s'}))
        polls = forms.CharField(max_length = 160, required=False, label="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'placeholder': (_'Enter poll option'), 'class': 'votes firstopt','id':'id_polls1','data-id':'1'}))
        ...
```

if i use like this, i take syntax error.

how can i translate "Type your question here" and "Enter poll option" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid syntax error is caused by the following code:

```
(_'Type your question here')
```

This should be:

```
_('Type your question here')
```

Answer (score 2):

Thhe `_` is just an identifier, just like `f`. When you call a function `f`, you do this with `f(…)`, so for `_` it is the same: `_(…)`.

You thus can fix the syntax errors with:

```
class CreatePollForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, label="", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1','cols':'20', 'placeholder': _('Type your question here'),'class': 'createpoll_s'}))
    polls = forms.CharField(max_length = 160, required=False, label="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'placeholder': _('Enter poll option'), 'class': 'votes firstopt','id':'id_polls1','data-id':'1'}))
```